# Ordering Big O-complexity function according to complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science

I'm trying to order the following functions in terms of Big O complexity from low complexity to high complexity:

```
100n, 2^n , 2^log^3 n , log^n, n^100 , log log n, 2^n^2, n^log n , n^√n , 2^2^n
```

Here, all logs are base 2.

I have ordered them following way. Is this order of Big O-complexity correct?

```
log n 
100n 
log log n
2^n
n^100
n^√n
n^log n
2^log^3 n
2^n^2
2^2^n
```

Comment: > Here, all logs are base-2: if you think the base of a logarithm is relevant to which big-O complexity class it is in, you may want to brush up on your conceptual understanding of asymptotic complexity

Comment: One way to spot check your answer is to plug in a really big value for `n`, say 10^100, and compare the results. While not mathematically rigorous it would be a good smell test. Doing this will reveal that no, they're not in order.

Comment: How did you calculate that 100n comes before log log n? Without seeing your calculations, it's hard to offer advice other than to learn the definition and how to apply it.

Comment: @GovindParmar Compare `O(2.9^n)` with `O(e^(n log(2.8))`. My conceptual understanding is fine, but I still believe that the base of the logarithm can matter to which big-O complexity class you get.

Comment: @btilly No... `logB0(N) = logB1(N) / logB0(B1)`, meaning that `O(logB0(N)) ∈ O(logB1(N))` and vice-versa. The base adds no information about the complexity class of the algorithm.

Comment: @GovindParmar No matter how many examples you can find where it doesn't matter, it still matters in the example I gave.  Because if we do natural logarithms, then `e^(n log(2.8)) = 2.8^n << 2.9^n`.  But with base 2 logarithms `e^(n log(2.8)) = 4.4168502...^n >> 2.9^n`.

Comment: @btilly Examples?? I used generic terms (`B0` for first log base, `B1` for second. (i.e. it's a statement) Note the key operation in your example is the exponentiation - `e^(EXPONENT)`, making it an `O(n^x)` class algorithm, not a logarithmic one.

Comment: @GovindParmar It has a `log`, and the base of said `log` affects the complexity class. The list of examples to compare we have `n^log n` where the same is true for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct order is:

```
log log n 
log n
100n
n^100
n^log n
n^√n
2^log^3 n
2^n
2^n^2
2^2^n
```

When comparing any two functions,

1. cancel out like terms.
2. apply 'log' on both sides => as many times as possible
3. substitute very large values for n => 2^100, 2^2^10 etc., (since logs are all base 2)